# Multi column with OR condition search not working in elastic search PHP

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am working in elastic search in laravel v5.3. I added the 15000 users in elastic search each user has username,full_name,is_live,id and now I want search user with username or full_name. below is my search array that I make

```
Array
(
    [index] => people
    [type] => people_list
    [from] => 0
    [size] => 1000
    [body] => Array
        (
            [query] => Array
                (
                    [bool] => Array
                        (
                            [should] => Array
                                (
                                    [match] => Array
                                        (
                                            [full_name] => v.n
                                            [username] => v.n
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But I always receive exception. Please guide in right way that how I can solve this problem

Comment: what is the exception you got?

Comment: @VajiraPrabuddhaka I simple explain I have following query that I want to convert in ealstic search json " SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE "%John Smith% OR full_name LIKE "%John Smith%" "

Comment: We understand your problem. Please, paste the exception you receive from Elastic Search.